# How to vectorize a set of items in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, vectorization

I am trying to take a set of arrays and convert them into a matrix that will essentially be an indicator matrix for a set of items.

I currently have a array of N items

```
A_ = [A,B,C,D,E,...,Y,Z]
```

In addition, I have S arrays (currently stored in an array) that are have a subset of the items in vector A.

```
B_ = [A,B,C,Z]
C_ = [A,B]
D_ = [D,Y,Z]
```

The array they are stored in would is structures like so:

```
X = [B_,C_,D_]
```

I would like to convert the data into an indicator matrix for easier operation. It would ideally look like this (it would be an N x S sized matrix):

```
[1,1,1,0,...,0,1]
[1,1,0,0,...,0,0]
[0,0,0,1,...,1,1]
```

I know how I could use a for loop to iterate through this and create the matrix but I was wondering if there is a more efficient/syntactically simple way of going about this.

Comment: are you familiar with [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org)?

Answer (score 1):

A concise way would be to use a [list comprehension.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
# Create a list containing the alphabet using a list comprehension
A_ = [chr(i) for i in range(65,91)]

# A list containing two sub-lists with some letters
M = [["A","B","C","Z"],["A","B","G"]]

# Nested list comprehension to convert character matrix 
# into matrix of indicator vectors
I_M = [[1 if char in sublist else 0 for char in A_] for sublist in M]
```

The last line is a bit dense if you aren't familiar with comprehensions, but its not too tricky once you take it apart. The inner part...

```
[1 if char in sublist else 0 for char in A_]
```

Is a list comprehension in itself, which creates a list containing 1's for all characters (`char`) in `A_` which are also found in `sublist`, and 0's for characters not found in `sublist`.

The outer bit...

```
[ ... for sublist in M]
```

simply runs the inner list comprehension for each `sublist` found in `M`, resulting in a list of all the sublists created by the inner list comprehension stored in `I_M`.

**Edit:**

While I tried to keep this example simple, it is worth noting (as DSM and jterrace point out) that [testing membership in vanilla arrays is O(N)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). Converting it to a hashlike structure like a [Set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) would speed up the checking for large sublists.

Comment: You can condense `1 if char in sublist else 0` to `int(char in sublist)`.  You could also speed it up somewhat (for large S) by using `for subset in map(set, M)` as it's faster to test membership in a large set than a large list.

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A_ = np.array(['A','B','C','D','E','Y','Z'])
>>> B_ = np.array(['A','B','C','Z'])
>>> C_ = np.array(['A','B'])
>>> D_ = np.array(['D','Y','Z'])
>>> X = [B_,C_,D_]
>>> matrix = np.array([np.in1d(A_, x) for x in X])
>>> matrix.shape
(3, 7)
>>> matrix
array([[ True,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

This is `O(NS)`.